# Reshape LSTM output to get desired output shape

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have a noob question: I built a very simple LSTM which takes windows of time-series data as input, in the shape `(batch_size, n_time_steps, n_features)`.

This is the LSTM:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.lstm_layer = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = self.lstm_layer(x)
        x = self.fc(out.squeeze())
        x = nn.functional.softmax(x, dim=2)
        return x
```

So, I would like the output (`x` in the code) to be in the shape `(batch_size, num_classes)`, because I would like to know the class for each window of data. However, right now the output shape is `(batch_size, n_time_steps, num_classes)`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

just add this line before the last line

```
x = np.delete(x, 1)
```